# Secure way to decode microsoft login idToken in cakephp

Tags: azure, cakephp, decode, msal.js, msal-react

Currently I am working with "Login with Microsoft" in my app. In my app, I am using react in client side and cakephp for backend. I am using [@azure/msal-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser) library in react. I have the following code in the frontend which initialized the msal with my microsoft clientId and call the loginPopup() method of MSAL object instance

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser'
const config = {
        auth: {
            clientId: 'REPLACE_WITH_OUR_MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID',
        },
    }
    const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(config)
const loginRequest = {
            scopes: ['user.read'],
        }
const res = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest)
```

From above code, I can see successful response with idToken, accessToken, and some other credentials.

Now, I want to send this idToken to the cakephp backend and I have to validate this idToken in php that this token trusted and verified token from Microsoft. I already have piece of code in cakephp that decode the token and check the clientId.

```
/// verify token 
$token = $values['token'];
$tokenParts = explode(".", $token);  
$tokenHeader = base64_decode($tokenParts[0]);
$tokenPayload = base64_decode($tokenParts[1]);
$jwtHeader = json_decode($tokenHeader);
$jwtPayload = json_decode($tokenPayload);
if ($jwtPayload['aud'] !== 'REPLACE_WITH_OUR_MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID') { // replace this with our microsoft client id
                return $this->response->body(json_encode(['error' => true, 'errorMsg' => 'Client id is wrong' ]));
            }
```

Now my concern is that I really can't trust this decoding token in cakephp since it seems like anyone can decode it without using any secret key or something. If anyone is clever and know my microsoft clientId, probably they can create a token which may contain our clientId and send to the endpoint. Basically I can't 100% trust my solution in cakephp. If it can be decode with a simple function `base64_decode()`, it's not secure for sure.

**Now my question is that what is the better way to authenticate the microsoft idToken in cakephp?**

Answer (score 1):

Idea of idToken comes from OpenId Connect specs. So idToken is simply JWT token which has 3 parts: header, payload, signature.
Using signature you can verify integrity of the token.

In short: token become invalid in case any changes in header or payload. OpenId Connect provider creates signature based on header and payload it puts in the token using its private key and its imposible for intruder to create correct signature because he has not this private key. That means if validation result is good - you can be sure this is good untouched token.

Great guide how you can validate the token:
https://curity.io/resources/learn/validating-an-id-token/